# Regex to detect ASCII art on a single line.

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Basically I want to find ASCII Art on one line.  For me this is any 2 characters that are not alpha numeric ignoring whitespace.  So a line might look like :

This is a !# Test of --> ASCII art detection @#@ <--

So the matches I should get are :

```
!#

-->

@#@

<--
```

I came up with this which still selects spaces :(

```
\b\W{2,}
```

Im using the following website for testing :
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Thanks for the help its much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
[^\w\s]{2,}
```

This will match any sequence of two or more characters that are *not* word characters (which include alphanumeric characters and underscores) or whitespace characters.

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B%5E%5Cw%5Cs%5D%7B2%2C%7D&input=This%20is%20a%20!%23%20Test%20of%20--%3E%20ASCII%20art%20detection%20%40%23%40%20%3C--)

If you would also like to match underscores as part of your 'ASCII art', you'd have to be more specific:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]{2,}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B%5Ea-zA-Z0-9%5Cs%5D%7B2%2C%7D&input=This%20is%20a%20!%23%20Test%20of%20--%3E%20ASCII%20art%20detection%20%40%23%40%20%3C--)

Comment: Actually, this won't limit the match to ascii, if its 'ascii' art he's interrested in.

Comment: @sln It would if the file / text OP's searching is ASCII. But yes, that's a reasonable point.

Comment: Ascii is 7 bit. Ascii files are byte oriented.

Answer (score 0):

I think this

`((?=[\x21-\x7e])[\W_]){2,}`

is probably equavalent to this

`[[:punct:]]{2,}`

Using POSIX, the supported punctuation is:
(to add more, just add it to the class `[[:punct:]<add here>]{2,}`

33 = !
 34 = "
 35 = #
 36 = $
 37 = %
 38 = &
 39 = '
 40 = (
 41 = )
 42 = *
 43 = +
 44 = ,
 45 = -
 46 = .
 47 = /
 58 = :
 59 = ;
 60 = <
 61 = =
 62 = >
 63 = ?
 64 = @
 91 = [
 92 = \
 93 = ]
 94 = ^
 95 = _
 96 = `
 123 = {
 124 = |
 125 = }
 126 = ~